# There is no 'New App' button to create an NVP/SOAP app

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, app-id

I'm trying to make a site similar to amazon and ebay.  I'm using Joomla, and furthermore, Quick2Cart.  I need to take a commission out of all sales, which is easy enough to do on Quick2Cart, but I have to use the Paypal Adaptive Payments plugin.  This plugin requires the api username, api password, api signature, and the app id.  The problem arose in trying to create a new nvp/soap app.  I followed the instructions in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/#register
but there is no 'new app' button in the left navigation bar.

Please help.  I can't find answers anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the notification at the top of the page:

> This portal will be permanently unavailable as of December 1, 2017

Comment: Than how do I create a new app?